# How to get text within a span tag with playwright?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I skimmed through similar questions, but all questions seem to be focused around 'locating span tag by text', but my goal is to 'get all texts within span tag'.

ex)

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080})
    page = context.new_page()

    url = 'https://announcements.bybit.com/en-US/?category=new_crypto&page=6'

    page.goto(url)
    page.wait_for_timeout(2000)

    print(page.get_by_test_id('//span').inner_text())

    x = page.locator("//span[text()='New Listing: TAMA/USDT — Grab a Share of the 4,000,000 TAMA Prize Pool']")
    x.click()
```

the above code detects a span tag by text, and clicks on it.

However, I cannot find a way to locate all  tags, and retrive all texts within the span tags.

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: If you want all span texts, why are you using `[text()='New Listing: TAMA/USDT — Grab a Share of the 4,000,000 TAMA Prize Pool']`? That xpath looks pretty specific to me. `get_by_test_id('//span')` doesn't make sense as an xpath in a test id locator.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find the <span> element using a CSS selector
span_element = page.query_selector("span")

# Get the text content within the <span> element
text = span_element.text_content()
print("Text within <span>:", text)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but it seems page.query_selector('span') return 'None' value

Answer (score 0):

Use [all()](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all) to get a list of all span elements:

```py
all_spans = page.locator('//span').all()

for span in all_spans:
    print(span.text_content())
```